# statistical modelling with 3 categorical predictor variables that are independent and a binary categorical response variable

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data, modeling

How does one perform logistic regression when your response and predictor variables are factors with two levels.I have three predictor variables with levels yes or no. My response variable is dead or alive. How do I visualise the data and fit an appropriate model?

Comment: That's not difficult for logistic regression for any software worth mentioning, so what you want to know about how to do it is unclear.  Your data define $2$ levels of response and $2^3 = 8$ combinations of three predictors. So, if you show us the combined $2 \times 8$ frequency table, you are likely to get several suggestions. One graph design for the Titanic data (more complicated than yours)  is at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/4932-designplot-now-available-from-ssc-something-also-for-fans-of-descriptive-tables

Comment: Please note that asking how to code something in your favourite software (whatever it is) would be off-topic here.

Comment: The graphs mentioned in my first comment are easier to see, and discussed at greater length, in https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gr0061